# How to indent html inline with vscode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

Hello I got this indent in the first image and I would like it to be like the second image. I can't figure how to do that, I tried to use extensions such as prettier and some others. I also tried to modify Word wrap settings in VScode but I am not able to do it. Does someone could give me an indication about how to do that. thanks a lot.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68R0W.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc6K6.png

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use  ALT + Shift + F

Comment: Thank you, but I already try that as well

Comment: Can you show me what did you get? Because for me, it worked